# data-hover not showing up when hovering over images

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a portfolio website and want the data-hover information to show up on the left bottom corner (I know I don't have the code written for that yet, it's because I haven't gotten it to show up at all!) when the mouse hovers over the image (both the thumb and the original). 
I've tried data-title and gotten the information to appear, but I don't think I can style it to the corner. Thank you for your time!
Best,
JTE

```css
.container2 {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.container2 li {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container2 li img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.container2 .hover {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container-2">

  <li class="work-item" id="001">
    <a href="work/IMG_0138.jpg" data-hover="Information about piece #1">
      <img class="thumb" src="work/IMG_0138 thumb.jpg" width="400" height="260" />
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="work-item" id="002" data-hover="Information about piece #2">
    <a href="work/NewGoogle_photo.jpg">
      <img class="thumb" src="work/NewGoogle_photo thumb.jpg" width="300" height="362" />
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="work-item" id="003" data-hover="Information about piece #3">
    <a href="work/_56A5502-1.jpg">
      <img class="thumb" src="work/_56A5502-1 thumb.jpg" width="300" height="160" />
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show an absolutely positioned pseudo-element (`::before`) when the link is hovered, and get it's `content` from `attr(data-hover)`:

```css
.container2 {
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

.container2 li {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

.container2 li img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.container2 .hover {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

a {
  position: relative;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
}

a:hover::before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: silver;
  content: attr(data-hover);
}
```

```html
<li class="work-item" id="001">
  <a href="work/IMG_0138.jpg" data-hover="Information about piece #1">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/400/260" width="400" height="260" />
  </a>
</li>

<li class="work-item" id="002">
  <a href="work/NewGoogle_photo.jpg" data-hover="Information about piece #2">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/300/326" width="300" height="362" />
  </a>
</li>

<li class="work-item" id="003">
  <a href="work/_56A5502-1.jpg" data-hover="Information about piece #3">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://picsum.photos/300/160" width="300" height="160" />
  </a>
</li>
```